# Pass arguments only when needed

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

As an example I have a function `f` and a variable `a=1`. 
Sometimes `f` needs `a` and I want to call `f(a=a)` and other times `f` has no arguments. How can I deal with that?

When I try to call `f(a=a)` (expecting that it will silently ignore the case where `a` is not used in `f`), I get the following TypeError:

```
f got an unexpected keyword argument 'a'
```

**Edit**

I want to implement a function `g` such that, given:

```
def f1(a):
    return a

def f2():
    return 1
```

we have:

```
g(f1, a) == a
g(f2, a) == 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to inspect a function's arguments.

For that, use the `inspect` module:

```
import inspect
def g(somefunc, *params):
    num_args = len(inspect.getargspec(somefunc).args)
    return somefunc(*params[:num_args])
```

Testing, with your functions:

```
def f1(a):
    return a

def f2():
    return 1

>>> print(g(f1, 3))
3
>>> print(g(f2, 3))
1
```

Comment: This works by counting the number of arguments and its great that you came up with this `inspect.getargspec`. I think we can do better with some kind of `filtered_params = arg for arg in params if arg in inspect.getargspec(somefunc))` and `return somefunc(*filtered_params)`

Answer (score 2):

use keyword dictionary in `f`:

```
def f(**kwargs):
    if 'a' in kwargs:
        print("a passed with value {}".format(kwargs['a']))
    else:
        print('a not passed')

f(a=12)
f()
```

prints:

```
a passed with value 12
a not passed
```

it makes argument testing/retrieving completely manual. You can do anything you want, and it can be generalized to several arguments.

This also forbids to pass arguments as positional like `f(12)` which is probably a good thing in your case.

```
>>> f(12)
Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: f() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

The drawback is that the caller cannot rely on parameter names to know what to pass. Either create a docstring, or people will have to read the code/guess...

Now to apply that to your edit, which kind of changes the problem I must say. So `f2` cannot be changed, in that cas the work must be done in the wrapper function:

```
def f1(a):
    return a
def f2():
    return 1

def g(f,arg):
    try:
        return f(a=arg)
    except TypeError:
        return f()

a=12
print(g(f1, a))
print(g(f2, a))
```

prints:

```
12
1
```

so "better ask forgiveness than permission": if we get a `TypeError` (raised when the parameter isn't known by the function), we just call the function *without* the parameter. The drawback if that if the first function returns a `TypeError`, we cannot know if it was the parameters or inside the function.

A workaround would be to inspect the error message and only call the function without parameters if the error message is about parameters:

```
def g(f,arg):
    try:
        return f(a=arg)
    except TypeError as e:
        if "unexpected keyword" in str(e):
            return f()
        else:
            raise e  # another TypeError, let it pass
```

Comment: `f` is unknown and unaccessible

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: It works if you can edit `f2` but you can't. `f2` is given and not editable.

Comment: see my edit. changed the wrapper so you don't need to edit `f2`. But I don't see that in your question, you should add this constraint, because it was only in your mind a few minutes ago.

Answer (score -1):

Simply specify the default argument in the function `def` line...

```
def f(a=1):
    return(a)
print(f()) #returns 1
print(f(a = 2)) #returns 2
```

---

For your next part (as you seemed to have switched your question with edits...

```
def g(f, a):
    return(f(a))
```

Comment: A lot of the other answers are python 2, this is written in python 3 as you tagged

Comment: `f` is unknown and unaccessible

Comment: @RodolpheLAMPE be sure that the `def` of the function is done before any function calls. I tested this code multiple times on python 3.6.